# Como acessar Maps no Genymotion

Tags: android, genymotion

Para usar o maps no Genymotion preciso criar alguma conta na play store? Quando acesso o aplicativo "Play Store" Fala que precisa atualizar

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Genymotion não vem com Play Services instalado. Você precisa instalar manualmente.

Este artigo explica o passo a passo para fazê-lo.

http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-install-google-services-on-genymotion/en